# Can we select count(query) from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT COUNT(ANOTHER SELECT QUERY) FROM DUAL.
```

Can we get the results this way or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

An example could help:

```
SQL> create table tabTest as (select 1 x from dual);

Table created.

SQL> select count( select * from tabTest ) from dual;
select count( select * from tabTest ) from dual
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL> select count(*) from (select * from tabTest);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived table (aka "sub-query")

```
select count(*)
from (
  .... your query here ...
);
```